# subadditivity proof

Tags: probability-theory

How do I prove:

$P(\bigcup E_n) \le \sum_1^\infty P(E_n)$

I understand here, I need to expand the Union and because I do not have the disjoint sets assumption, the fallout will prove it. How do I represent this?

(This is not a homework problem, I am trying to learn stuff)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** We show how your strategy can be carried out. Define sets $A_1,A_2,A_3,\dots$ as follows.

Let $A_1=E_1$. Let $A_2=E_2\setminus E_1$. Let $A_3=E_3\setminus(E_1\cup E_2)$. And so on.

Then the union of the $A_k$ is the same as the union of the $E_k$. But the $A_k$ are pairwise disjoint. `

Comment: Does this same technique apply for countably finite sets?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by countably finite. It applies to unions indexed by finite sets, like $\bigcup_1^n E_k$, and to unions indexed by the natural numbers, like your $\bigcup_1^\infty E_k$. The "making sets pairwise disjoint" can be extended to unions of sets indexed by ordinals. But for uncountable ordinals we lose the second part necessary for the proof, that the probability of the union is the sum of the probabilities.